# Do developers in India pay income or sales tax from income from the sale of apps?

Tags: india, sole-proprietorship, vat

I'm a developer based in India who wants to sell apps, either on one of Apple's app stores or directly.

Do I need to pay VAT on the proceeds, or income tax, or both? Do I need a TIN?

Where can I read more about this?

I'm a sole proprietor, not a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that Service tax need not be paid if the turnover is less than 9 lakhs.  I dont know about vat.

Comment: This answer would be better with some references.

Answer (score 0):

Income tax, yes. VAT only if the turn over is Rs 30 lacs (? Don't recollect)